Android studio's android virtual device does not open in Arch after update
I tried using android virtual device which worked before but now it stops running after updating it.
Error message:
❯ android-studio
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2024-05-13 12:51:00,258 [    820]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlags <clinit> requests com.android.tools.idea.flags.StudioFlagSettings instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-05-13 12:51:01,201 [   1763]   WARN - #c.i.n.i.NotificationGroupManagerImpl - Notification group Logcat is already registered (group=com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup@7ea4be6d). Plugin descriptor: PluginDescriptor(name=Android, id=org.jetbrains.android, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=/opt/android-studio-canary/plugins/android, version=241.15989.150.2411.11792637, package=null, isBundled=true)
2024-05-13 12:51:07,006 [   7568]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
2024-05-13 12:51:10,007 [  10569]   WARN - #com.android.ddmlib - * daemon started successfully
2024-05-13 12:51:12,870 [  13432]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.progress.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Errors during XML parse:
2024-05-13 12:51:12,871 [  13433]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.progress.RepoProgressIndicatorAdapter - Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.
2024-05-13 12:51:24,961 [  25523]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel Fold API 30 - Emulator terminated with exit code 127
2024-05-13 12:51:24,963 [  25525]   WARN - #c.i.u.j.JBCefApp - JCefAppConfig.class is not from a JBR module, url: jar:file:/opt/android-studio-canary/lib/lib.jar!/com/jetbrains/cef/JCefAppConfig.class (Use JBR bundled with the IDE)
2024-05-13 12:51:25,961 [  26523]   WARN - #com.android.sdklib.deviceprovisioner.DeviceAction - The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Fold_API_30 has terminated.
com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$EmulatorTerminatedException: The emulator process for AVD Pixel_Fold_API_30 has terminated.
    at com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.EmulatorConnectionListener$WaitForEmulatorTask.run(EmulatorConnectionListener.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.RwLockHolder$executeOnPooledThread$1.run(RwLockHolder.kt:154)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:702)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:699)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

How can I fix this "jetbrains" class issue?

Uninstall the Jetbrains Toolbox, Remove Android Studio after backing up your project files.  Redownload the new toolbox from the AUR, and use the new toolbox to reinstall Android Studio.

However, @eyoung100 I did not have it in the first place when it worked before. After updating the android studio, no matter whether I uninstall or reinstall with clearing cache and so on the error still persist even if I've installed the jetbrain's toolbox like you have suggested.

If you're on Windows: Press the Windows Key + R, type appdata, Browse to \LocalLow\Android Studio <version>\tmp\logs\idea.log, Open idea.log in Notepad, Ctrl +F: Search for SEVERE, Somewhere above SEVERE will be an entry that says Android Studio was Unable to start the emulator with a description, It will most likely say, not enough space.  See here and here

@eyoung100 I am using it in my Arch Linux OS... NOT WSL on MS Windows OS.

Just Find idea.log and open it.

@eyoung100 where is that located as I could not find with fzf? I found a idea.properties though which had these in it: ```
idea.config.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio/config
idea.system.path=${user.home}/.AndroidStudio/system
idea.plugins.path=${idea.config.path}/plugins
idea.log.path=${idea.system.path}/log ``` and many more

Try Help > Show idea.log

I've solved the issue by installing lib32-libbsd package from Arch AUR.

Post your solution as an answer and you can accept your own answer to gain reputation points.

@FaisalAhmedMoshiur That's an odd fix  I would think the needed functions would be embedded in the Java Bundle that came with the Jetbrains JRE.  Congratulations on solving it.

The issue is solved by installing lib32-libbsd from Arch repo.
